# Pandas - New column based on the value of another column N rows back, when N is stored in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with example data:

```
idx    price    lookback
0      5    
1      7        1
2      4        2
3      3        1
4      7        3
5      6        1
```

Lookback can be **positive** or **negative** but I want to take the **absolute value** of it for how many rows back to take the value from.

I am trying to create a new column that contains the value of `price` from `lookback + 1` rows ago, for example:

```
idx    price    lookback  lb_price
0      5        NaN       NaN
1      7        1         NaN
2      4        2         NaN
3      3        1         7
4      7        3         5
5      6        1         3
```

I started with what felt like the most obvious way, this did not work:

```py
df['sbc'] = df['price'].shift(dataframe['lb'].abs() + 1)
```

I then tried using a lambda, this did not work but I probably did it wrong:

```py
sbc = lambda c, x: pd.Series(zip(*[c.shift(x+1)]))
df['sbc'] = sbc(df['price'], df['lb'].abs())
```

I also tried a loop (which was extremely slow, but worked) but I am sure there is a better way:

```py
lookback = np.nan
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i, 'lookback']:
        if not np.isnan(df.loc[i, 'lookback']):
            lookback = abs(int(df.loc[i, 'lookback']))
    if not np.isnan(lookback) and (lookback + 1) < i:
        df.loc[i, 'lb_price'] = df.loc[i - (lookback + 1), 'price']
```

I have seen examples using `lambda`, `df.apply`, and perhaps `Series.map` but they are not clear to me as I am quite a novice with Python and Pandas.

I am looking for the fastest way I can do this, if there is a way without using a loop.

Also, for what its worth, I plan to use this computed column to create yet another column, which I can do as follows:

```py
df['streak-roc'] = 100 * (df['price'] - df['lb_price']) / df['lb_price']
```

But if I can combine all of it into one really efficient way of doing it, that would be ideal.

**Solution!**

Several provided solutions worked great (thank you!) but all needed some small tweaks to deal with my potential for negative numbers and that it was a lookback + 1 not - 1 and so I felt it was prudent to post my modifications here.

All of them were significantly faster than my original loop which took **5m 26s** to process my dataset.

I marked the one I observed to be the fastest as accepted as I improving the speed of my loop was the main objective.

**Edited Solutions**

From Manas Sambare - 41 seconds

```py
df['lb_price'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: df['price'][x.name - (abs(int(x['lookback'])) + 1)]
    if not np.isnan(x['lookback']) and x.name >= (abs(int(x['lookback'])) + 1)
    else np.nan,
    axis=1)
```

From mannh - 43 seconds

```py
def get_lb_price(row, df):
    if not np.isnan(row['lookback']):
        lb_idx = row.name - (abs(int(row['lookback'])) + 1)
        if lb_idx >= 0:
            return df.loc[lb_idx, 'price']
        else: 
            return np.nan

df['lb_price'] = dataframe.apply(get_lb_price, axis=1 ,args=(df,))
```

From Bill - 18 seconds

```py
lookup_idxs = df.index.values - (abs(df['lookback'].values) + 1)
valid_lookups = lookup_idxs >= 0
df['lb_price'] = np.nan
df.loc[valid_lookups, 'lb_price'] = df['price'].to_numpy()[lookup_idxs[valid_lookups].astype(int)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vectorized version (i.e. no for loops) using numpy array indexing.

```
lookup_idxs = df.index.values - df['lookback'].values - 1
valid_lookups = lookup_idxs >= 0
df['lb_price'] = np.nan
df.loc[valid_lookups, 'lb_price'] = df.price.to_numpy()[lookup_idxs[valid_lookups].astype(int)]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     price  lookback  lb_price
idx                           
0        5       NaN       NaN
1        7       1.0       NaN
2        4       2.0       NaN
3        3       1.0       7.0
4        7       3.0       5.0
5        6       1.0       3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

By getting the row's index inside of the df.apply() call using row.name, you can generate the 'lb_price' data relative to which row you are currently on.

```
%time
df.apply(
    lambda x: df['price'][x.name - int(x['lookback'] + 1)]
    if not np.isnan(x['lookback']) and x.name >= x['lookback'] + 1 
    else np.nan,
    axis=1)

# > CPU times: user 2 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 2 µs
# > Wall time: 4.05 µs
```

**FYI:** There is an error in your example as idx[5]'s lb_price should be 3 and not 7.

Comment: I would consider breaking this up onto multiple lines or using a regular function so it is clearer how it works.

Comment: Corrected my example, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example which uses a regular function

```py
def get_lb_price(row, df):
    lb_idx = row.name - abs(row['lookback']) - 1
    if lb_idx >= 0:
        return df.loc[lb_idx, 'price']
    else: 
        return np.nan

df['lb_price'] = df.apply(get_lb_price, axis=1 ,args=(df,))
```

Comment: This solution works but did not account for potential negative numbers so I made a small change.

Comment: Didn't notice you said lookback can be negative. I fixed the code.

Answer (score 1):

This solution loops of the values ot the column `lockback` and calculates the index of the wanted value in the column `price` which I store as a list.

The rule it, that the lockback value has to be a number and that the wanted index is not smaller than 0.

```
new = np.zeros(df.shape[0])
price = df.price.values
for i, lookback in enumerate(df.lookback.values):
    # lookback has to be a number and the index is not allowed to be less than 0
    # 0<i-lookback is equivalent to 0<=i-(lookback+1)
    if lookback!=np.nan and 0<i-lookback: 
        new[i] = price[int(i-(lookback+1))]
    else:
        new[i] = np.nan
df['lb_price'] = new
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'p' is not defined`